# How to get AppendTo() working in my live page?

Tags: jquery

I have 2 links that control 2 tab content areas below them. I'm trying to use appendTo() to move `<div id="myResponsiveDivID"></div>` from inside `<div id="map-wrapper-0"></div>` to inside `<div id="map-wrapper-1"></div>`  when you click on either of the 2 links.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="mapTabs">
    <li class="choosemaps">choose your map:</li>


<script>
$("#map-swap-button-0").click(function () {

      $("#myResponsiveDivID").appendTo('#map-wrapper-0'); 

    });
</script>
<li class="active"><a href="#yate-map" id="map-swap-button-0" data-toggle="tab" onclick="jQuery.fn.axZm.zoomSwitch('yate-map.png'); return false;" class="yate-mapselector">Yate and Chipping Sodbury</a></li><script>
$("#map-swap-button-1").click(function () {

      $("#myResponsiveDivID").appendTo('#map-wrapper-1'); 

    });
</script>
<li><a href="#wickwar-map" id="map-swap-button-1" data-toggle="tab" onclick="jQuery.fn.axZm.zoomSwitch('wickwar-map.png'); return false;" class="wickwar-mapselector">Wickwar</a></li>    </ul>
```

Then there's the myResponsiveDivID DIV that I'm trying to move:

```
<div id="map-wrapper-0">
<div id="myResponsiveDivID" class="axZmBorderBox">
</div>

<div id="map-wrapper-1">
</div>
```

As you can see in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qv2s2spv/), the code I'm trying to implement does actually work (you'll need to view source of fiddle to see the div appending). But when the code is on my live page it doesn't work. When I go to the console I don't get any js errors, and I've done lots of testing but I'm struggling to see why appendTo() is not working?

Comment: Try wrapping your jQuery with `$(document).ready(function() {...})`

Comment: Please show code here! http://SSCCE.org

Comment: Please see: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Sorry @mplungjan I've now added the code.

Comment: @ahb that's it! Oh dear, so much trouble and such a silly mistake :( Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try change jQuery click to on, example:

```js
$('.parent').on('click', '.live-child', function() {
  //action
})
```

.parent is element which always exist on the page, .live-child is element which is live load for example through ajax